# combine both javascript events together not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Having trouble to combine both javascript events together
Both class actions occurred in different clicks.

```
<script>
    //first event
    $("#add-product-details-video").click(function () {
        hideAlertMsg();
    });
    //second event
    $(".add-more-image").on('click', function () {
        hideAlertMsg();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your comment you are missing comma between multiple element selectors:

```
$("#add-product-details-video .add-more-image").click(function () { hideAlertMsg(); });
```

Should be

```
$("#add-product-details-video, .add-more-image").click(function () { hideAlertMsg(); });
```

Comment: thanks, now its working

Comment: @manu glad to help